Switching I2C between two master MCUs
I am working on a PCB with 2 MCUs - ESP32 and STM32. On the same PCB I have various sensors working on the bus.

Would my I2C circuit work?
I have a question about SGM3002XMS: can I supply it with 5 volt or 3.3 volt?
After the MCP23017 I have 2 I2C sensors. Do I have to put pullup resistors on each i2c sensor?
As the STM32 would be master by default, when the STM32 switch the 2 IN pins to go to ESP32, do I have to reset the ESP32 for the ESP32 to be master at his turn?



Treat each MCU as slave or master so, to hand the baton to the other MCU send it a "special" master-to-slave message and revert the current master to slave. The "special" message to the slave will be interpreted as it being told to become master. No need for extra lines or hardware.

how to make esp32 to become master how to switch between them i have no idear ?

The current master relinquishes control by sending a message to the slave that it should become master. At that point, the current master turns itself into a slave and the slave that the master previously informed turns itself into the new master. No special hardware.

@KhalesNaim That's down to your program to determine.

I going to try this and make some researches thanks

@KhalesNaim if we are done here, please take note of this: What should I do when someone answers my question. If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.

Thanks Andy i have review your solution on the net  but as my code is already  very heavy i really prefer a hardware solution to make a flip flop between the 2 masters.


No, because the expander chip I2C bus is pulled to 5V, and the ESP cannot hande that. The STM32 has 5V tolerant pins, so it might, if those specific pins are 5V tolerant.

You can supply it from 5V or 3.3V. But it will pass signals up to the supply.

You need single set of pull-ups per segment. If there are more chips on same segment, you need one set of pull-ups.

It depends how you want to do the switchover. You can do that if you want. But it is not a good idea to simply move the chips to STM32 in the middle of a bus transaction performed by ESP.


It is unclear why you even want this. One MCU could be slave to a single master, or both MCUs could be multimaster.

Thanks for your reply I going to explain more:

1 The esp32 is before the bidirectional level shifter so esp32 will work on 3.3 volt.
2 If i supply the vcc  switch pin with 3.3 volt Do the vcc pin would affect the COM NO and NC pin of the circuit?
4 I want to both MCU to be multi master when Stm32 witch is master by default to give the master to esp32.
